# Cannot connect to Ubuntu China sources.

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-manager, repository

I have my computer installed choosing the default sources server. Then today I encountered this error:

```
Err:10 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release                      
  Connection failed [IP: 218.11.10.30 80]
...
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
...
```

The sources list is here: [Ubuntu wiki](http://wiki.ubuntu.org.cn/)

I switched several servers in the site above.
I also tried `apt clean` and several methods.

However, when I followed the [PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure), **it worked well when switched to main server**.

I wonder why this occurred?

BTW, the server is much faster than the main server for my network, so I prefer to the former one.

Comment: The local server you were using was probably down at the time. Change it back later and try again.

Comment: How did that happen? I think there should be many servers in the whole country.

Answer (score 1):

I change the sources.list to another server(NetEase 163 Mirrors), then the problem was fixed.